# Nodejs/Puppeteer How to iteratively scrape website without restarting another puppeteer instance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to web scrape with puppetter, currently the following code works but I think there can be optimizations made one of which I think is to only use one puppetter instance. But I don't really know how to do that. Can anyone help me?
This is the working but slow original:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function scrapeProduct(url) {
    
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    const [el] = await page.$x('xpath of element');
    const txt = await el.getProperty('textContent');
    const rawTxt = await txt.jsonValue();

    browser.close();
    
    return rawTxt;

}



async function something() {
    var some_varible = the length of some array;
    process.setMaxListeners(some_varible);

    for (var i = 0; i < some_varible; i++) {
        var target = some_array[i].Name
        var url = 'somewebsite' + target;
        console.log(target + ": " + await scrapeProduct(url));
    }


}

something();
```

This is my pathetic attempt at not using multiple instances of puppeteer: (Does not work)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function scrapeProduct(url, page) {
    
    await page.goto(url);

    const [el] = await page.$x('xpath of element');
    const txt = await el.getProperty('textContent');
    const rawTxt = await txt.jsonValue();
    
    return rawTxt;

}



async function something() {
    var some_varible = the length of some array;
    process.setMaxListeners(some_varible);
    
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    for (var i = 0; i < some_varible; i++) {
        var target = some_array[i].Name
        var url = 'somewebsite' + target;
        console.log(target + ": " + await scrapeProduct(url, page));
    }
    browser.close();

}

something();
```

Comment: What's the problem you have with the second code?

Comment: You are correct, launch and close each time the browser is not quite optimal, instead, you should open the browser once during application start up and keep the reference to the instance. You will be passing this instance of the `browser` to your `scrapeProduct` function and this function will open new tab (`page`), process given URL and close this page after processing. This can be done asynchronous, as the browser able to process the pages in multiple tabs (pages).